# How to insert an activity like walking in google fit in android programmatically

Tags: android, google-fit

I need to insert a activity in google fit with calories ,duration, steps and distance parameters . Does anyone knows how to do it . Whether i use historyApi or SessionApi ..I am very Confused on that.I read the getStart guide of google fit but did.t get any solution ..

Comment: First hit on google fit api create activity: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions Webpage has sample code

Comment: Yeah i read this before too . but i need to insert duration distance ,steps and calories too along with activity name . Just like in googlegfit android app add activity page . How to insert those fields along with activity name

Comment: Right now i am only able to add activity name by using this link

Comment: I did it finallly ...by creating different data sources for each

Comment: Great that you have it working. For any next question on StackOverflow. Please provide a clear question and code example what you have tried or what you have found out.

Comment: ok..i didn't attached the code because i used the same code as on google fit dev console

Comment: can you share your working code?you used history api or sessions?